# Why doesn't Android ask for the desired camera app from within my own app?

Tags: android, camera

I have a button that leads to whatever camera app is installed on the phone, and this works fine. However, on some phones, the camera app does not return any results, and one app returns a corrupted image. I've installed another nicer camera app onto those phones, but I can't get it to run while the old camera apps are installed.

Isn't Android supposed to automatically ask me which app I want to use if there are multiple candidates? Do I need to do something else within my app to make it do this?

Edit: This is even on phones that have never had a "Choose default Camera app" dialog in their lives. Even if I use Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose camera app"); the chooser never appears.

Here's the code I use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_TAKEPHOTO);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [createChooser(](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)) method of the Intent class. 
Your code would look something like that.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose cam application"), RESULT_TAKEPHOTO);
```

Comment: I've had a look at this, but this only appears when the normal one would appear anyway, the only difference being that you can't select a default one to run instead of showing the picker (which would be desirable in this case, to only choose the first time). In my case, even this forced version does not show the picker. It's as though no other camera app has it's intent tags set up correctly, so it doesn't respond to the chooser. This doesn't make sense, so I've just been assuming it is my app's fault somehow.